# Is it OK to leave this switch ungrounded?

Tags: electrical

[image][image]I am changing outlets in my house and the old outlet did not have a grounding screw. Is it necessary to ground? How unsafe is it? The box is plastic so I can't ground it to the box.

Comment: Is that a bare wire in the back of the switch box I see in the third photo?

Comment: Also, do you have copper or aluminum?

Comment: Aluminum...you responded to one of my other posts last week.

Comment: Ah yes -- sorry about re-asking, late night brain fart :)

Comment: So yes -- in the back of the switch box, is that a bare wire coiled up in there? Perhaps you could pull the wires out further and get us another photo?

Comment: yes, i can get another photo tonight and post it. Thanks.

Comment: If you plan to continue aluminum wire in service, get AFCI breakers.

Comment: I have added two more pictures showing the wire that was in the back of the box. It wasn't grounded to anything back there, it was loose. Is that okay? Is this the grounding wire?

Comment: Unfortunately, we'll need a bigger/better photo yet still...

Comment: I will try to get a better photo. Its hard to get a picture the way these wires are positioned. The wire is completely bare and was just by itself in the back of the box. The switch I removed had no grounding screw. It is possible they just left the ground wire in the back of the box? The box is plastic.

Comment: I have added a bigger/better photo. There is a clamp on this wire and it is attached to 2 or 3 others. Pretty sure this is a grounding wire...right?

Answer (score 1):

### There's a ground there, so use it

Since the box has a grounding wire in it (it's the bare wire crimp-connected to the other bare wires), you'll need to hook it up to the switch, as per NEC 404.9(B) (the exceptions are not shown here as they do not apply to your case):

> **(B) Grounding.** Snap switches, including dimmer and similar control switches, shall be connected to an equipment
>   grounding conductor and shall provide a means to connect
>   metal faceplates to the equipment grounding conductor,
>   whether or not a metal faceplate is installed. Snap switches
>   shall be considered to be part of an effective ground-fault
>   current path if either of the following conditions is met:
>
> (1) The switch is mounted with metal screws to a metal
>   box or metal cover that is connected to an equipment
>   grounding conductor or to a nonmetallic box with integral means for connecting to an equipment grounding
>   conductor.
>
> (2) An equipment grounding conductor or equipment
>   bonding jumper is connected to an equipment grounding termination of the snap switch.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I connected the bare wire that was crimped together in the back to the ground terminal on the switch.